# Note or a poem?

Tags: грамматика

[image: Picture of a note/poem I found]
Hi I was wondering if one of you could help me translate this.

Comment: http://www.simonov.co.uk/waitforme.htm

Comment: Original text of the poem: http://militera.lib.ru/poetry/russian/simonov/02.html .   I don't like the English translation above because of too many exclamation marks.  There are no exclamation marks in the original poem.

Comment: Voted to close. The poem is brilliant, still request for translation is what it is, and rules set for this forum are rules (even when we do not enjoy them applied to some particular case).

Answer (score 1):

That's the famous poem by Konstantin Simonov written in 1941 (1942?).
Addressed by a generalised frontline soldier to his wife. There'd be English translations in the Net, I believe. The general sense is like: "Wait for me and I'll be back ... but you'll have to wait with all your heart... wait when noone else waits... and then [because of your waiting] I'll be back". Created some adverse reception in its time, being perceived as a sort of rigid moral law (for wives and girlfriends of soldiers).

Comment: Wiki article about the poem (in Russian wikipedia): http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Жди_меня_(стихотворение)